# Tipsy is changing my images back to text

Tags: tooltip, tipsy

I'm using Tipsy with WordPress. I have the images all set up, but when I try to use the plugin it changes the image back to text. Why?

```
<img title="top-left" src="IMAGE.PNG" alt="" width="170" height="120" />
```

Comment: Hi, can you show some JS code?